# How to disable all fields after a certain message shows up

Tags: c#, winforms

English is not my first language, sorry if I make any mistakes.

So I need to disable my "Reset Password" button after it has been clicked once. This will only happens when user already reseted his password. He can't reset his password "twice in a row", I can't use a timer btw.

When you click "Reset Password" an email is sent with the new password.
I was thinking about displaying a messagebox showing "An email was sent with the new password." and then disable all fields forcing the user to close the form.

But thing is, I don't know how to (I'm a beginner btw.)

This is the form:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I52ZA.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: You can simply disable the button in the Click Event